# I am getting an undeclared identifier error but I have included the header file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to create a program to help me understand stacks a bit better, and I came across this error while trying to implement templates into my header file. It is saying a bunch of undeclared identifier errors, as well as a char unexpected when trying to create a new object in the main.cpp.

I have already tried just making sure the header file works, so a blank main.cpp and just including the header file and it compiles like that, but when right when I try to create a new object from the header file class, I get the errors. I have spent some time online trying to find something similar but they all seem pretty specified to their problem which wasn't helping too much with mine.

//Here is part of my header file:

```
#ifndef STACKASLLIST_H
#define STACKASLLIST_H
using namespace std;

template<typename T> class StackAsLList
{
private:

    struct StackNode
    {
        T ch;
        StackNode<T> *next;
    };
    StackNode<T> *top;

public:

    StackAsLList();     
    void ClearStack();  /// Remove all items from the stack
    void Push(T ch);    /// Push an item onto the stack
    T Pop();            /// Pop an item from the stack
    bool isEmpty();     /// Return true if stack is empty
    bool isFull();      /// Return true if stack is full

    ~StackAsLList() /// Class destructor
    {
        ClearStack();
    }
};
```

//Here is my main.cpp where I try to implement the header file:

```
#include "StackAsLList.h"
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //this is the line where I start getting errors
    StackAsLList<char>*theStack = new <char>StackAsLList();
}
```

I expect to be able to run the program and use the functions I have created in the class, but I keep on receiving undeclared identifier errors. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The compiler ignores all lines above `#include "pch.h"` so `#include "StackAsLList.h"` is ignored. This is a function of how precompiled headers work on Visual Studio. reverse the order of those 2 lines and it should work. I would post that as an answer but I am sure there are duplicates for this.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm used to Visual Studio precompiled headers being named `stdafx.h` so I totally missed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
#include "StackAsLList.h"
#include "pch.h"
```

to

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "StackAsLList.h"
```

Comment: So that actually fixed part of it, but I'm still getting an issue with this line:  
    StackAsLList<char>*theStack = new <char>StackAsLList();

Comment: @AdamCarter please ask a new different question about that totally different problem.

Comment: oop, sorry, I thought it was part of the problem, my bad.

Comment: @AdamCarter StackAsLList<char>*theStack = new StackAsLList<char>();

Comment: At StackOverflow the main purpose of a question is to help future readers with the same 1 problem. If you ask multiple questions in the same question it does not become a good question to help future readers.

Comment: I'm new here. Why make that switch?